# Call grandchild function from a child - vue.js

Tags: vue.js, parent-child, emit

I have 4 components in vue, I want to call a grandchild function('refreshArtifact') from a child component, any idea how can I do it?

So here is my component hierarchy:

**Parent** : TeamManagment.vue

**Children** :TeamPlatform.vue & ManagementArtifcts.vue

**GrandChild** : TeamAction.vue (TeamPlatform.vue child)

i want to call the 'refreshArtifact' function in **TeamAction.vue** from the **ManagmentArtifact.vue** component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can't right now directly call a child function of a brother. So, with your code, you can't directly call a function of a component A, from a component B which is the brother of the A one.

But, you can do that with the grandparent component.
So, when the `ManagmentArtifact.vue` component need to call `refreshArtifact` function, you can emit an event. The `TeamManagment.vue` listen that event, and then pass use `ref` of `TeamPlatform.vue component` to call the function.

`ManagmentArtifact.vue`: `this.$emit('callRefresh')`
`TeamManagment.vue`: `<ManagmentArtifact @callRefresh='refreshArtifact' />`
`<TeamPlatform ref='team' />`
`methods: { refreshArtifact(){ this.$ref.team.refreshArtifact() } }`

You can read the doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html).

Comment: I did as follow and it's not work: in ManagementArtifact i put:  this.$emit('refreshartifact'), in TeamManagement i put:   @refreshartifact="$emit('refreshartifactaftersave')" (inside team-platform tag) and in TeamPlatform i put: @refreshartifactaftersave="refreshArtifacts()" (inside teamAction tag.) am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't saw that you just want execute a function, without using data. So the props are not the good way. In fact, you can use the ref instead of props to just call a child functiion. I've edited my answer to solve that.